# Timezone using the sample event from VA

Tags: botframework

I am trying to get the users timezone via the class TimeZoneInfo that is shipped with the skill template and utilised in the calendar skill.
It's working when testing the code locally but not when it's deployed to azure where it seems to give the standard timezone of UTC

As an example when I want to return the timezone

```
 private async Task<DialogTurnResult> TimeZoneAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        dynamic data = new { id = TimeZoneInfo.Local };
        var response = TemplateEngine.GenerateActivityForLocale("TimeZoneMessage", data);
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(response);

        return await stepContext.NextAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
```